# How to install Woopra tracking code in Angular 2

Tags: angular, woopra

I was wondering which would be the best way to install Woopra tracking code on an Angular 2 app. I have added the tracking code to the **index.html**

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var t,i,e,n=window,o=document,a=arguments,s="script",r=["config","track","identify","visit","push","call","trackForm","trackClick"],c=function(){var t,i=this;for(i._e=[],t=0;r.length>t;t++)(function(t){i[t]=function(){
            return i._e.push([t].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0))),i}})(r[t])};for(n._w=n._w||{},t=0;a.length>t;t++)n._w[a[t]]=n[a[t]]=n[a[t]]||new c;i=o.createElement(s),i.async=1,i.src="//static.woopra.com/js/w.js",e=o.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e.parentNode.insertBefore(i,e)
    })("woopra");
    woopra.config({domain: 'My.Domain.com.'});
    woopra.track();
</script>
```

I can access the global variable **woopra** on all needed components via `window["woopra"]`, but I am wondering if it would be better adding the code into some config file like **webpack.common.js** and then export the variable.

Does somebody know a better approach? thanks

Comment: Don't you just want to put it on the HTML page? why would you want to put it on every component?

Comment: Woopra is not just for tracking page views, you can also track all kind of custom events, for example: ``woopra.track('form_submitted');``, ``woopra.track('customer_clicked_somewhere');``  That's why the global variable **woopra** should be shared across the whole site.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now:)

Answer (score 0):

The Woopra node package already has a type definition file:

https://github.com/Woopra/node-woopra/blob/master/index.d.ts

Unfortunately, it looks like the latest npm package is out-of-date (v0.1.1).

So... first update to the latest version:

Update to version 0.2.0 (latest version on github):

```
npm update woopra@0.2.0
```

The second thing that's unfortunate is that they didn't include `index.d.ts` as part of the npm package.

So I recommend copying index.d.ts from here:

```
https://github.com/Woopra/node-woopra/blob/master/index.d.ts
```

and putting it somewhere in your source directory:

```
src/woopra.d.ts
```

Then add the type definition to your package.

**package.json**

```
{
    typings: 'index.d.ts'; // this is **your** main d.ts file
}
```

**index.d.ts** (for your package)

```
import * from '...'; // your other type definitions
import * from './<path_to_src>/woopra.d.ts';
```

Wow! This is harder then it should be... hopefully the author updates the npm package so it deploys the d.ts file. It should work... but maybe its a work-in-progress and there might be a reason they didn't include the d.ts file. If so, maybe raise an issue on Github?

Comment: But how should I define the **wopra** variable following this approach? can it be used globally straight away? And what about the initialization with the domain name, etc, or should I just keep the code in the index.html combined with this typing?

Comment: Yes, once you add it to your` typings`, `tsc` will know about the `woopra` interface.  I suggest putting the code in its own ts file: i.e. `woopra.ts`, and including it whenever you need to reference it:    `import * from './woopra';`